# How do plants intake minerals through their leaves?

Tags: biochemistry, botany, plant-physiology

How do plants intake the fertilizer when it is sprayed all over the leaf surface as a foliar feed?

Comment: A nice review by [Wocjik (2004)](http://www.insad.pl/files/journal_pdf/journal_2004spec/full2004-24spec.pdf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They absorb minerals through pores in the leaves known as [stomata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoma), this is some what similar to the way a medicine patch is absorbed on human skin except for the fact that the human skin has sweat pores instead of stomata.

[Here](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/Tomato_stoma_observed_through_immersion_oil.gif) is a animation of them opening and closing on a tomato plant provided by Wikipedia:

sources:

> A nice review by [Wocjik (2004)](http://www.insad.pl/files/journal_pdf/journal_2004spec/full2004-24spec.pdf) (from the comments)
>
> http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-foliar-feeding.htm
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foliar_feeding
>
> http://cronodon.com/BioTech/Plant_Transport.html